# Material UI DatePicker custom renderInput

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, datepicker

I recently started using material-ui in my React + TypeScript project.
The code below was written based on the sample code on the official website.

```
import AdapterDateFns from '@mui/lab/AdapterDateFns';
import DatePicker from '@mui/lab/DatePicker';
import LocalizationProvider from '@mui/lab/LocalizationProvider';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const SampleDatePickerOriginal = () => {
  const [date, setDate] = useState<Date>(new Date());

  const onChangeHandler = (_date: Date | null, keyboardInputValue?: string) => {
    if (_date) {
      setDate(_date);
    }
  };
  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
      <DatePicker
        onChange={onChangeHandler}
        value={date}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
};

export default SampleDatePickerOriginal;
```

I wanted to use input element instead of TextField in this code.
So I referred to material-ui's issue (https://github.com/mui/material-ui-pickers/issues/1751) and wrote the code below.

```
import AdapterDateFns from '@mui/lab/AdapterDateFns';
import DatePicker from '@mui/lab/DatePicker';
import LocalizationProvider from '@mui/lab/LocalizationProvider';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const SampleDatePickerCustom = () => {
  const [date, setDate] = useState<Date>(new Date());
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const onChangeHandler = (_date: Date | null, keyboardInputValue?: string) => {
    if(_date){
      setDate(_date);
    }
  };

  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
      <DatePicker 
        onChange={onChangeHandler}
        onClose={() => {setIsOpen(false);}}
        open={isOpen}
        value={date} 
        renderInput={({
          ref,
          inputProps,
          disabled,
          onChange,
          value,
          ...other
        }) => (
          <div ref={ref}>
            <input
              style={{ display: 'none' }}
              value={date.toISOString()}
              onChange={onChange}
              disabled={disabled}
              {...inputProps}
            />
            <button onClick={() => {setIsOpen(!isOpen);}}>
              OPEN
            </button>
          </div>)} />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
};

export default SampleDatePickerCustom;
```

This code works fine, but the calendar that opens is in the upper left corner.
How can I make it appear just below the button like when I use TextField?

Comment: Any solution to this? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: @roonz11 Just saw that you were looking for an answer today and I was trying to figure this one out as well today. Hope my answer helps!

Answer (score 3):

I was stuck on the same problem here today and luckily got it working for me now.

The idea is that you have to pass an anchor element to the Material UI Popper component, which is basically the wrapper for your Datepicker Popup.
That means you have to create a ref object for your custom input and pass that to the popper object as `anchorEl`.
If you check the MaterialUI X [documentation for the Datepicker API](https://mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/date-picker/), you can see it under the Props section as [PropperProps](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/popper/).

Your code then would look something like this:

```js
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';

const SampleDatePickerCustom = () => {
  const [date, setDate] = useState<Date>(new Date());
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const customInputRef = useRef();

  const onChangeHandler = (_date: Date | null, keyboardInputValue?: string) => {
    if(_date){
      setDate(_date);
    }
  };

  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
      <DatePicker 
        onChange={onChangeHandler}
        onClose={() => {setIsOpen(false);}}
        open={isOpen}
        value={date} 
        PopperProps={{ anchorEl: customInputRef.current }}
        renderInput={({
          ref,
          inputProps,
          disabled,
          onChange,
          value,
          ...other
        }) => (
          <div ref={ref}>
            <input
              style={{ display: 'none' }}
              value={date.toISOString()}
              onChange={onChange}
              disabled={disabled}
              ref={customInputRef}
              {...inputProps}
            />
            <button onClick={() => {setIsOpen(!isOpen);}}>
              OPEN
            </button>
          </div>)} />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
};
```

The only things that I added are the `customInputRef` object, which is assigned as a ref to your input and the `PropperProps` object on your Datepicker, which only has one property, the `customInputRef.current` element.
That should make the Popper be anchored at the provided custom input element.
I didn't type the additions, since I'm not the best at TS, but I hope it's enough to understand how it works :)

Comment: thanks @Nickfis . Unfortunately this still displayed in the top left corner for me. I posted a workaround (not ideal)

Comment: I was using this sample, but was getting an error "The `anchorEl` prop provided to the component is invalid.", and the popup was showing up on the top left.  I ended up using the `customInputRef` on the div instead and it worked.  No warnings and the popup shows beside the Button.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to work around it by using TextField but hiding it with styles...
`<TextField style={{ opacity: 0, width: 0, height: 0 }} {...params} />`

```js
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
   <DatePicker
    open={calendarOpen}
    onClose={() => setCalendarOpen(false)}
    value={date}
    onChange={(newValue) => setDate(newValue)}
    renderInput={(params) => (
      <div>
      {/* HACK: this next line was needed to get the calendar to render in the right position */}
        <TextField style={{ opacity: 0, width: 0, height: 0 }} {...params} /> 
        <Button
          className="p-1"
          variant="outlined"
          onClick={() => setCalendarOpen((calendarOpen) => !calendarOpen)}>
          <CalendarIcon />
        </Button>
      </div>
    )}
  />
</LocalizationProvider>
```